# In memory key store that saves itself to disk?

Tags: database, keystore, in-memory-database

I've used redis in the past. I believe that it's in memory but loses all information when it 'exits'. Is there an in memory key store that saves itself to disk?

Comment: Redis can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Redis (RDB) does that, but it does so by taking periodic snapshots. There are other Redis persistence options described here: https://redis.io/topics/persistence

I've never used Kyoto Filing Cabinet, but I believe it is persistent by nature
http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/

There is a Kyoto microservice implementation called Kyoto Tycoon:
http://fallabs.com/kyototycoon/